# Объясните логику работы выражения

Tags: java, c++, битовые-операции

Объясните пожалуйста, как работает это выражение `!(a & (a - 1))`
В плюсах совершенно не понимаю, в Java `!` нельзя применять к `int`.

```
        private int isPow2(int a)
        {
          return !(a & (a - 1));
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Возьмем два числа `A` и `B`. 
 
Выражение `A & B` будет равно `0` только тогда, когда числа `А` и `B` не содержать единичных бит на одних и тех же позициях.

Если `(a & (a - 1) = 0`, то `a` и `a-1` не содержат общих единичных бит.

Давайте возьмем число `а` и попробуем вычесть одну единицу.

Когда мы отнимаем единицу, смотрим на младший бит. если он равен 1 то мы просто заменяем его на 0. Но если там стоит 0, то мы должны заимствовать из старшего бита. Мы заменяем каждый бит с 0 на 1 до тех пор, пока не найдем бит, равный 1. Затем вы инвертируем найденную единицу в ноль.

То есть чтобы получить ноль при выполнении операции `&`, нам нужно, чтобы младшие нули в `a` соответствовали единицам в `a - 1`, а последний(и единственный) единичный бит в `a`(если существует) стал бы нулем в `a - 1` - только таким образом во всех позициях будут отсутствовать единичные биты.

Это условие выполняется только, если

1. число является степенью двойки, например

   ```
   1000 & 0111 = 0
   10000 & 01111 = 0
   ```
2. число равно 0

   ```
   0000 & 1111 = 0
   ```

Поэтому `(a & (a - 1)) = 0`, если **а - степень двойки или ноль**

Answer (score 5):

Операция `a&(a-1)` обнуляет крайний справа единичный бит или дает 0, если такового нет:

```
a       = 01011000
a-1     = 01010111
a&(a-1) = 01010000
```

Таким образом, для всех `a`, являющихся степенями двойки (у которых только один бит - единичный, остальные - нулевые) и 0, выражение дает 0, для чисел, таковыми не являющимися - ненулевое значение. `!` инвертирует полученное *логическое* значение (0 - `false`, не нуль - `true`), так что ваша функция дает 1, если `a` - степень двойки **или нуль**, и нуль в противном случае.